# How to Pass a variable from one function to an other in the same Controller?

Tags: laravel, methods, controller

I have two methods in my controller.

##### Method Number one

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search_text = $_GET['search'];
}
```

This method is getting me the value entered in the search bar input via `$search_text` variable.

My goal here is to use that variable in another method.

##### Method Number Two

```
public function searchFilter(Request $request)
{
    $brand = $request->marque;
    $disponible = $request->disponibilite;
    $souscat = $request->sous_categorie;
}
```

I have tried using the session and `__construct` but didn't work.

Comment: Your issue is that you are trying to reuse controller's methods related to routing. You do not do that in Laravel, you have to either create a `protected` or `private` method (you can also use `public`) that NO route is using and that's it, a normal PHP call that has nothing to do with Laravel. Also have in mind that you are using `$_GET` (a global variable) and Laravel uses either `$request` (if it is a `Request` class) or the helper `request()`, but not global variables. Check this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#accessing-the-request)

Comment: hmm if you did understand the issue is there a way I can achieve what am trying to achieve ?

Comment: You did not understand my reply, I am telling you that you can, creating another method that is not used in Routing, like a normal PHP class. This is basic PHP, honestly has nothing to do with Laravel. Even if it was Laravel, you cannot understand how to call another method, that is PHP not Laravel. But again, create another method, and call that method, basic PHP. Do you require help with that?

Comment: yes please I need help

Comment: Before answering, how do you use these controllers? Do they use different `GET/POST` route requests? Or only `search` method is being accessed by a request then you want to execute method `searchFilter` from `search`?

Comment: So In the `search` method I am searching based on the inputs field, and that's input I want to use it in the `searchFilter` method so I can filter based on that input value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need two methods for that, I think that you're calling `searchFilter` as a post request or something like that, and in your query string you have the `search` attribute, so you could use `$request` to get all values in your url, you just need to call the actual attribute that comes from the route parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-input-via-dynamic-properties

Or even you could use this method `$request->query('search')` to get the value for that attribute.

Comment: the `search` method is retrieving me inputs and based on those inputs I want to filter in the `searchFilter`  method.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out I used session

```
My First Method:

public function search(Request $request)
{
$search_text = $_GET['search'];
session()->put('search_text', $search_text);
}
```

My Second Method

```
public function searchFilter(Request $request)
{
    $search_text = session()->get('search_text');
    dd($search_text);
}
```

**// OUTPUT**

```
what ever The searched value was
```